# Better way to handle mulitple boolean variables in function call

Tags: c++, function, design-patterns, boolean

Logic is to call a function with some input values and function returns multiple boolean variables.

In Future the boolean variables may be extended.

```
function(inp1,inp3,bool1,bool2... booln)
```

I decided to pack the boolean variables into structure

```
function(inp1,inp3,struct bool_flags)
```

Kindly help me out for an effective design

Comment: Do you need [std::optional](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/optional) ?

Comment: What's wrong with [`std::bitset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset)?

Comment: It seems you're doing something similar to permission flags. Why not use an int or a byte and set each digit as a 1 or 0? Then with bitwise ops you can tell which part is true or false.

Comment: Or use a structure with bit fields.

Comment: As you can see, there are many ways to do this. Please show what you've tried, and we'll help you get it working.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure what you are trying to accomplish here as the question is unclear, but I have an idea. You could pack all the booleans into a `uint` or a `ulong`. Then, each bit of the variable is one boolean. You can read the boolean's like so:

```
uint bools;
bool bool0 = bools & 1;
bool bool1 = (bools >> 1) & 1;
etc...
```

You can write the booleans like so:

```
bools |= bool0;
bools |= bool1 << 1;
etc...
```

This works by logical shifting, anding, and oring the values. Boolean values in C++ are a 1 or a 0. So to read, you shift the "container" variable then `&` the bool value. To write, you shift the bool value and `|` it with the "container".

The only flaw in this is that ints are limited to 32-bits and longs are 64-bits. You may be able to create a struct of ints or longs for more efficient packing if needed. Good luck!